# svprogresshud not showing on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

On viewdidload of my tableviewcontroller i have the following

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
[self getData];
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

On the getData method, i am using AFNetworking to get the data from my backend api. Since that is an asynchronous call, i would expect my SVProgressHUD to show.

```
  -(void) getData {
     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * reqManager =AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
     AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    //set auth token..etc 
   [reqManager GET:urlString parameters:nil 
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //code for success....
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       //code for failure
    }];
}
```

But it's not showing at all. So obviously i am working on my main thread. Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are showing hud immediately after method call like

```
[self getData];
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

This is the problem. Move dismiss code to

```
-(void) getData {
     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * reqManager =AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
     AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    //set auth token..etc 
   [reqManager GET:urlString parameters:nil 
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //code for success....
             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       //code for failure
              [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }];
}
```

You can see the `dismiss` call in success and failure of webservice call, and call the `getData` method by

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
[self getData];
```

remove the `[SVProgressHUD dismiss]` from here.

Comment: on the success/failure call, should i not be doing dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ { [SVProgressHUD dismiss];});  ??

Comment: @cableload AFNetworking calls its `success` and `failure` blocks on the main queue (unless you explicitly override the `completionQueue`). So, no, dispatching back to the main queue is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that it's not showing on the main thread, but rather that it's showing and being dismissed so quickly that you're not seeing it. This is because `GET` is an asynchronous method.

The solution is to adopt a completion handler pattern, namely a block of code that `getData` will call when the asynchronous method finishes:

```
- (void)getDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))completionHandler {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    //set auth token..etc
    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //code for success....

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //code for failure

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(error);
        }
    }];
}
```

And

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
[self getDataWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
   [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}];
```

This pattern allows you to defer the calling of `dismiss` until the asynchronous process is done, but it also keeps the `SVProgressHUD` code together in a single area (rather than scatter it about and burying UI related code inside your networking methods).